# Tensorboard Debugger V2 not displaying data

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorboard

I am trying to debug a Nan training issue, and thought to use Tensorboard Debugger V2 to do so. I implemented it with this line at the top of my training code:

```
tf.debugging.experimental.enable_dump_debug_info(OUTPUT_FOLDER + 'tensorboard' +
                                                    "/debug/tfdbg2_logdir",
                                                    tensor_debug_mode="FULL_HEALTH",
                                                    circular_buffer_size=-1)
```

However, no data shows on Tensorboard even though the folder is being populated with log data. Both are version 2.9.0
[image]

Answer (score 0):

My issue when encountering this problem was that my log files were 0 KB; check to make sure your logs are actually valid.  Mine worked when using NO_TENSOR mode (the default), and I still have to troubleshoot why the other methods aren't working.

Also, please check if fully disabling eager mode works, which requires more than just one line:

```
tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)
tf.data.experimental.enable_debug_mode()
model.compile(run_eagerly=True)
```